# Issue with LINQ with a variable where clause

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

First time posting a question so I apologize in advance if I make a mis-step.

I have a widows form application that includes a list box for users to make one or multiple selections.  This feeds a LINQ query to return them the data they want.  When the user makes a singular selection the query works, but when multiple entries are selected the query returns 0 results.

Here is the query:

```vb
assets = From anitem In myTable
         Where String.Equals(cboStatus.SelectedItem.ToString,
             anitem.Field(Of String)("Status"),
             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) _
         And Integer.Parse(anitem.Field(Of String)("Days Late")) <= intDays _ 
         And Enumerable.Range(0, facilities.Count).All(Function(i) _
             anitem.Field(Of String)("Facility").Contains(facilities(i))) _
         Select anitem
         Order By Integer.Parse(anitem.Field(Of String)("Days Late")) Ascending
             Select Facility = anitem.Field(Of String)("Facility"), _
             Zone = anitem.Field(Of String)("Zone"), _
             Building = anitem.Field(Of String)("Building"), _
             Floor = anitem.Field(Of String)("Floor"), _
             DeviceName = anitem.Field(Of String)("Device_Name"), _
             FullName = anitem.Field(Of String)("Full Device Name"), _
             DaysLate = Integer.Parse(anitem.Field(Of String)("Days Late")), _
             Status = anitem.Field(Of String)("Status"), _
             UserName = anitem.Field(Of String)("Username"), _
             Assignment = anitem.Field(Of String)("Assignment"), _
             ResponsibleParty = anitem.Field(Of String)("ResponsiblePartyName")
```

I think the issue is in the "And Enumerable.Range..." part of the code.

The 3 things that are being used as criteria are number of days, status, and location  I need to return all records that are over the number of days, at a given status, and at any of the selected locations.

I think I am close, but I am missing something and I hope someone could please help.

Comment: I would also make variables before the query and use them in the query and not the expression - cleaner query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're using your `.Contains` int he right way? What happens if you write this? I believe that `facilities` is a list of your selected locations?

```
assets = From anitem In myTable
         Where String.Equals(cboStatus.SelectedItem.ToString,
             anitem.Field(Of String)("Status"),
             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) _
         And Integer.Parse(anitem.Field(Of String)("Days Late")) <= intDays _ 
         And facilities.Contains(anitem.Field(Of String)("Facility")) _
         Select anitem
         Order By Integer.Parse(anitem.Field(Of String)("Days Late")) Ascending
         Select Facility = anitem.Field(Of String)("Facility"), _
         Zone = anitem.Field(Of String)("Zone"), _
         Building = anitem.Field(Of String)("Building"), _
         Floor = anitem.Field(Of String)("Floor"), _
         DeviceName = anitem.Field(Of String)("Device_Name"), _
         FullName = anitem.Field(Of String)("Full Device Name"), _
         DaysLate = Integer.Parse(anitem.Field(Of String)("Days Late")), _
         Status = anitem.Field(Of String)("Status"), _
         UserName = anitem.Field(Of String)("Username"), _
         Assignment = anitem.Field(Of String)("Assignment"), _
         ResponsibleParty = anitem.Field(Of String)("ResponsiblePartyName")
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much. Yes facilities was an array that held the users choices.  I need to brush up on this.  Thank you again!